# Custom infowindow for fusiontable; binding issue - undefined property

Tags: javascript, google-maps, binding, prototypejs, google-fusion-tables

I'm using Derek Eder's fusion table template: https://github.com/derekeder/FusionTable-Map-Template/

Awesome stuff and I've been able to add various kml layers and filters etc. However it has got to the point where I want to add custom google maps infowindows instead of the default fusion table ones.

https://plnkr.co/edit/PF4AXXCefoWSbKoYcL9I?p=preview

The above plunker (mostly stripped of function etc) shows how I've tried to add the custom info window. It is found in js/maps_lib.js lines 106:111.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(self.searchrecords), 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent('<b>hello</b>');
    infowindow.open(self.map, self.searchrecords);
};

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Version 2 of the plunker works (without the above code).
The error I catch in V3 acc to console is 
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__e3_' of undefined"

From what I understand "undefined" in this context is most likely an error attributed to binding.
To var self = this I have added the following:

```
this.infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
{ content: '<b>hello</b>'}
);
```

Lines 93:95.

I suspect I need to use prototype somewhere but I'm not sure how to implement it.  I have read the following about binding: http://alistapart.com/article/getoutbindingsituations
but still am stuck.

// EDIT

```
MapsLib.prototype.submitSearch = function(whereClause, map) {
    var self = this;
    //get using all filters
    //NOTE: styleId and templateId are recently added attributes to load custom marker styles and info windows
    //you can find your Ids inside the link generated by the 'Publish' option in Fusion Tables
    //for more details, see https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/using#WorkingStyles
    self.searchrecords = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
      suppressInfoWindows: true,
      query: {
        from: self.fusionTableId,
        select: self.locationColumn,
        where: whereClause
      },
      styleId: 2,
      templateId: 2
    });
    self.fusionTable = self.searchrecords;
    self.searchrecords.setMap(map);
    self.getCount(whereClause);
  };
```

So far so good, however I now want to add my infowindow...

```
google.maps.event.addListener(self.searchrecords, 'click', function(e) {e.infoWindowHtml = "Name" + e.row['Name'].value;}
    );

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Again I get the "Cannot read property '__e3_' of undefined" error. Which I believe is an error regarding self.searchrecords...

Comment: `From what I understand "undefined" is an error attributed to binding` huh? in what sense? The error you are getting is that some code is trying to access somevar.__e3_ - but somevar is undefined

Comment: @JaromandaX Ahh sorry not in all cases, but in this context I think(!) it's undefined as some "this" reference points to the window object, which is lacking in properties. I don't have a somevar nor do I know how to fix this?

Comment: well, it wont be "somevar", it will be some var :p

Comment: @JaromandaX so it could be any var?! lol

Comment: without going into the code, no idea, I rarely follow links in questions - what I really wanted to know is what you meant by the statement I highlighted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MapsLib.prototype.submitSearch = function(whereClause, map) {
    var self = this;
    self.searchrecords = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
      suppressInfoWindows: true,
      query: {
        from: self.fusionTableId,
        select: self.locationColumn,
        where: whereClause
      },
      styleId: 2,
      templateId: 2
    });
    self.fusionTable = self.searchrecords;
    self.searchrecords.setMap(map);
    self.getCount(whereClause);

    google.maps.event.addListener(self.searchrecords, 'click', function(e) {
    if(self.infowindow) self.infowindow.close();
    else self.infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    self.infowindow.setContent(
    '<div class="tabs">' +
    '<ul>' +
    '<li><a href="#tab-1"><span>Building</span></a></li>' + //tab name
    '</ul>' +
    '<div id="tab-1">' + //first tab content
    '<p>Viewing data from: <b>'+ e.row['Last Modified'].value + '</b></p>' +
    '</div>'
    );
    self.infowindow.setPosition(e.latLng);
    self.infowindow.open(map);
  })};
```

Finally got it working with the above!